# The extra space problem in the html with Chinese language generated by gitbook

Tags: html, markdown, cjk, gitbook

I am using gitbook and github pages to build my homepage. The main language is Chinese. But I find that gitbook add a extra space in some place which is not nessesary. The following is the text in the markdown file

[image]

The output html appear a extra space between "参 与", which is not allowed in Chinese text.

[image]

I know this extra space is added by gitbook which think the text is English. I don't know how to config gitbook to deal with such problem. So I need your help. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line break between those two characters in your Markdown.

This is an issue with HTML and the browser and is not specific to Markdown. Under normal circumstances, your browser will treat any whitespace character as a space. In other words, your browser will display a line break as a space character. As you have manually added a line break between those two characters, the Markdown parser retains the line break in the HTML it outputs and the browser respects the line break by displaying a space. Therefore, you need to remove the line break from the Markdown source text.

If you want to keep you lines from being too long within your source, then you can add a line break at the last space before the current line break.